# ImportError: No module named urls in django deployment with mod_wsgi?

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have tried every solution suggested in the Internet. I have still not been able to solve this problem. My project hierarchy looks like this:

```
genalytics/
    ├── fileupload
    │   ├── backend.py
    │   ├── backend.pyc
    │   ├── backends.py
    │   ├── backends.pyc
    │   ├── django.wsgi
    │   ├── encrypt.py
    │   ├── encrypt.pyc
    │   ├── forms.py
    │   ├── forms.pyc
    │   ├── functions.py
    │   ├── functions.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── middleware.py
    │   ├── middleware.pyc
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── models.pyc
    │   ├── static
    │   │   ├── admin
    │   │   │   ├── css
    │   │   │   │   ├── base.css
    │   │   │   │   ├── changelists.css
    │   │   │   │   ├── dashboard.css
    │   │   │   │   ├── forms.css
    │   │   │   │   ├── ie.css
    │   │   │   │   ├── login.css
    │   │   │   │   ├── rtl.css
    │   │   │   │   └── widgets.css
    │   │   │   ├── img
    │   │   │   │   ├── changelist-bg.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── changelist-bg_rtl.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── chooser-bg.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── tool-right.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── tool-right_over.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── tooltag-add.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── tooltag-add_over.gif
    │   │   │   │   ├── tooltag-arrowright.gif
    │   │   │   │   └── tooltag-arrowright_over.gif
    │   │   │   └── js
    │   │   │       ├── actions.js
    │   │   │       ├── actions.min.js
    │   │   │       ├── admin
    │   │   │       │   ├── DateTimeShortcuts.js
    │   │   │       │   ├── ordering.js
    │   │   │       │   └── RelatedObjectLookups.js
    │   │   │       ├── calendar.js
    │   │   │       ├── collapse.js
    │   │   │       └── urlify.js
    │   │   ├── css
    │   │   │   ├── datepicker.css
    │   │   │   ├── datePicker.css
    │   │   │   ├── jquery-ui.css~
    │   │   │   ├── pro_dropline.css
    │   │   │   ├── pro_dropline_ie.css
    │   │   │   ├── screen.css
    │   │   │   └── screen.css~
    │   │   ├── endless_pagination
    │   │   │   └── js
    │   │   │       ├── endless.js
    │   │   │       ├── endless_on_scroll.js
    │   │   │       └── endless-pagination.js
    │   │   │   ├── transfer.png
    │   │   │   ├── ui-icons_454545_256x240.png
    │   │   │   ├── upload.png
    │   │   │   └── up.png
    │   │   ├── js
    │   │   │   ├── endless-pagination.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery
    │   │   │   │   ├── Copy of custom_jquery.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── custom_jquery.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── date.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery-1.4.1.min.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.bind.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.datePicker.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.dimensions.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.filestyle.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.pngFix.pack.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.selectbox-0.5.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.selectbox-0.5_style_2.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.selectbox-0.5_style_3.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.tablesorter.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.tooltip.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── jquery.usermode.js
    │   │   │   │   ├── ui.checkbox.js
    │   │   │   │   └── ui.core.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery-1.9.1.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery-latest.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery.pajinate.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery.tablesorter.js
    │   │   │   ├── jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js
    │   │   │   ├── test.js~
    │   │   │   └── transfer.js
    │   │   ├── login.css
    │   │   ├── PIE.htc
    │   │   ├── style.css
    │   │   └── style.css~
    │   ├── svn-commit.tmp
    │   ├── tasks.py
    │   ├── tasks.py~
    │   ├── tasks.pyc
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   ├── ajax.html
    │   │   ├── base.html
    │   │   ├── create_session.html
    │   │   ├── create_session.html~
    │   │   ├── deleted_files.html
    │   │   ├── edit_session.html
    │   │   ├── file_info.html
    │   │   ├── footer.html
    │   │   ├── forgot_password.html
    │   │   ├── form.html
    │   │   ├── header.html
    │   │   ├── list_files.html
    │   │   ├── list_session.html
    │   │   ├── list_session.html~
    │   │   ├── login_backend.html
    │   │   ├── message_forgot.html
    │   │   ├── nav.html
    │   │   ├── new_password.html
    │   │   ├── notify.html
    │   │   ├── overview.html
    │   │   ├── overview.html~
    │   │   ├── password_successful.html
    │   │   ├── reform.html
    │   │   ├── registration
    │   │   │   ├── password_reset_complete.html
    │   │   │   ├── password_reset_confirm.html
    │   │   │   ├── password_reset_done.html
    │   │   │   ├── password_reset_email.html
    │   │   │   └── password_reset_form.html
    │   │   ├── right.html
    │   │   ├── search_result.html
    │   │   ├── shared_by_me.html
    │   │   ├── shared_with_me.html
    │   │   ├── style.css
    │   │   ├── synced.html
    │   │   ├── test.html
    │   │   ├── test.html~
    │   │   ├── thanks.html
    │   │   ├── uploaded_files.html
    │   │   ├── uploaded_files.html~
    │   │   └── uploaded_notify.html
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   ├── views.py~
    │   └── views.pyc
    ├── genalytics
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── settings.py~
    │   ├── settings.pyc
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── urls.pyc
    │   ├── wsgi.py
    │   ├── wsgi.py~
    │   └── wsgi.pyc
    └── manage.py
```

Apache error in log file:

```
user@galaxy:/etc/apache2/log$ cat error.log | tail
[Sun Jun 23 15:48:17 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Sun Jun 23 15:48:17 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response
[Sun Jun 23 15:48:17 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Sun Jun 23 15:48:17 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Sun Jun 23 15:48:17 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163]     if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
[Sun Jun 23 15:48:17 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
[Sun Jun 23 15:48:17 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Sun Jun 23 15:48:17 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Sun Jun 23 15:48:17 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163]     __import__(name)
[Sun Jun 23 15:48:17 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.163] ImportError: No module named urls
```

**Apache httpd.conf file**

```
Listen 8000

<VirtualHost *:8000>
   ServerName NFS

   DocumentRoot /opt/genalytics


   WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/genalytics/genalytics/wsgi.py
   <Directory /opt/genalytics/genalytics>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>

   Alias /static /opt/genalytics/fileupload/static

</VirtualHost>
```

**wsgi.py file:**

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/opt/genalytics')

# We defer to a DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE already in the environment. This breaks
# if running multiple sites in the same mod_wsgi process. To fix this, use
# mod_wsgi daemon mode with each site in its own daemon process, or use
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "genalytics.settings"
#os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "genalytics.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I am using Django 1.5.

Comment: Do not set DocumentRoot to be a parent directory of where your source code lives. If that WSGIScriptAlias directive were inadvertently commented out, people would be able to download your Django settings.py file with passwords for databases in it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Do you know why I am getting No module named URLs Error?

Comment: SO is a very bad place to try and debug problems. Unless someone can quickly tell you what the issue is, you are better off using a mailing list for either Django or mod_wsgi as appropriate.